# OpenMP Multithreading on a Random Password Generator

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, random, openmp

I am attempting to make a fast password generator using multithreading with OpenMP integrated into Visual Studio 2010.

Let's say I have this basic string generator that randomly pulls Chars from a string.

```
srand(time(0)); 
for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    s=pwArr[rand()%(pwArr.size()-1)];
    pw+=s;
}

return pw;
```

Now, the basic idea is to enable multithreading with OpenMP to enable really fast random char lookup, like so:

```
srand(time(0)); 
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    s=pwArr[rand()%(pwArr.size()-1)];
    pw+=s;
}

return pw;
```

However, this only makes each thread do their own separate implementation of the password generator at the same time, and I end up getting repeats in my string.

An example output would be

```
ndxP1k1kP1k
```

Furthermore, this has terrible consequences with larger strings: Debug Assertation Failed error.

Am I just using the wrong tool for the wrong job?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you need to parallelize password generation. This shouldn't really take that long. The problem you're going to run into is that rand() isn't a re-entrant function so it isn't parallelizable in the way you want. I'm not sure if there are parallelized implementations, but I would suggest determining if you really need this in the first place.

Comment: @CrazyCasta, `rand()` has a re-entrant version called `rand_r()` which takes the PRNG state vector as argument, so that many generators can be driven concurrently with different states.

Comment: @derp, I assume that `pw` is `std::string` or similar type. The probability that the `+=` operator is neither thread-safe nor atomic is very high, hence you'd need to synchronise the call in a critical section, which would kill any performance gain from running this code in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, and turn @CrazyCasta's comment into an answer:

*Yes, you are using the wrong tool for the wrong job*

`rand` isn't parallelisable as you want it to be, and since generating a password of any reasonable length is very fast already it's difficult to see why you would bother.

However, the topic of parallel pseudo-random number generators is an interesting one and there is a lot of published work on them, even some questions and good answers here on SO.  I suggest you direct your attention to some more learning and return to your programming when you know some more about them.